ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json (SQLSTATE 22P02)

type ComputeConfig struct {
    DbId
    DbOwnerAudit
    DbTimeAudit
    Name     *string       `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    Type     ComputeType   `gorm:"column:type" json:"type"`
    Endpoint *string       `gorm:"column:endpoint" json:"endpoint"`
    Config   *pgtype.JSONB `gorm:"column:config" json:"config"`
}

func (db PostgresDB) CreateConfig(ctx context.Context, config *model.ComputeConfig) error {
    err := db.WithContext(ctx).Create(config).Error
    return err
}

[96.007ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "compute_config" ("created_by","updated_by","name","type","endpoint","config","id") VALUES ('alex@gmail.com',NULL,'Compute config','DB','https://databricks.com','{"account_id":"acc_id","client_id":"client_id","cluster_id":"cluster1"}','95b17051-095e-4393-9aec-496d88a05cf6') RETURNING "id","created_on","updated_on"

GORM is not able to insert this struct but when I'm running the query directly on the console then it is able to.
Error from gorm:
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json (SQLSTATE 22P02)
Token "" is invalid. 
JSON data, line 1: ...

Dependencies
gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.5.11
gorm.io/gorm v1.25.12
go 1.21

Have tried everything to solve this.. Tried different go versions still not able to resolve this issue
Table Definition
-- auto-generated definition
create table compute_config
(
    id         uuid                     default uuid_generate_v4() not null
        constraint pk_compute_config
            primary key,
    created_by text,
    updated_by text,
    created_on timestamp with time zone default now()              not null,
    updated_on timestamp with time zone,
    name       text                                                not null,
    endpoint   text                                                not null,
    type       compute_type                                        not null,
    config     jsonb
);

alter table compute_config
    owner to postgres;

API Request Body
 {
        "name": "Compute Config",
        "type": "DB",
        "endpoint": "https://databricks.com",
        "config": {
            "account_id": "acc_id",
            "client_id": "client_id",
            "cluster_id": "cluster1"
        }
    }

Function used to convert to JSONB meta
func ConvertMapToJSONB(data map[string]interface{}) (*pgtype.JSONB, error) {
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    jsonb := &pgtype.JSONB{}
    err = jsonb.Set(jsonData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return jsonb, nil
}


It would help to know the table definition...

added @LaurenzAlbe

Thank you. Running the INSERT statement against that table doesn't cause an error for me, so I cannot reproduce the problem.

How do you parse your request body?
If you parse your request body like this:
var result ComputeConfig
err = json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &result) // reqBody is []byte read from request body
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error unmarshaling JSON:", err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Parsed JSON successfully:", result)
}

You don't need to convert the Config to JSONB using ConvertMapToJSONB(). The json Unmarshal will convert it for you.
I got it working with this.

Maybe you could provide more details about how you parse your request body.
